# Need to find out a drop offs from purchasing per type of user

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

My client need to find out a drop offs in purchasing process per type of user and per type of industry.

FYI- these both user type and industry type need to select the user while registring to the website. And user can see the products only once they loggedin.

So, what needs to be done for achieving this to track in google dashboard

thanks

Comment: Voting to close. Not a programming specific question. A configuration question that might be better off in Webmaster section.

Answer (score 0):

On Login set the user type and industry as session scoped [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets).  Go to your analytics account, property settings, custom definitions, create a custom dimension, set scope to session (that way you need it to set only once per session, with a hit based dimension you'd need to send this with every pageview).

On your login confirmation page add the custom dimension:

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'usertype',
  'dimension2':  'industry',
});

Custom dimensions are specified as key/value pairs; the key is he string "dimensions" plus the numeric index of the dimension, the values you'd have to extract from your backend for each user when he logs in. It takes at least 24 hours until values for custom dimensions show up (well, at least for me).

Based on those custom dimensions you can create segments in the Analytics interface and do any analysis you like. You should probably create a  goal with a funnel for your sales, and then apply the segment to the funnel view (or the goal flow view) to see where users drop of.